# Bilinear upsample in tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, interpolation, image-resizing

I want to do a simple bilinear resize (not necessarily by an integer factor) in TensorFlow. For example, starting from a (32,3,64,64) tensor, I would like a (32,3,96,96) tensor, where each 64x64 has been rescaled by a factor of 1.5 using bilinear interpolation. What is the best way to do that?

I would like this to support arbitrary factors > 1, not just 1.5 specifically.

Note: the operation on each 64x64 would be the same as what `skimage.transform.rescale (scale=1.5, order=1)` does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) should do what you need. It accepts both 3d (single image) and 4d (batch of images) tensors, with arbitrary depth (number of channels). So this should hopefully work:

```
# it's height, width in TF - not width, height
new_height = int(round(old_height * scale))
new_width = int(round(old_width * scale))
resized = tf.image.resize_images(input_tensor, [new_height, new_width])
```

Bilinear interpolation is the default so you don't need to specify it. You could also use [resize_bilinear](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_bilinear) directly.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.  I wonder, is it possible to backpropagate through resize_images?

Comment: @AlexI is is possible to do this? Backpropogate through the resize?

Comment: @mattdns Yes, absolutely. You can backprop through resize as it's a linear operator.  Tensorflow does this with no problem.

Comment: @RawMean Don't edit bugs in - before r0.10 height and width are different arguments, look at the docs

Comment: @etarion It might have been, but it's not anymore.  Do you really want your answer refer to a deprecated API that does not compile anymore?

Comment: @RawMean r0.11 was released 15 days ago, not everybody has updated yet. And the answer clearly mentions both versions.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest *not* to use any of the `tf.image.resize_*` functions as [they suffer from a nasty bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591669/tf-image-resize-bilinear-vs-cv2-resize/50611485#50611485) that will [not be fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6720#issuecomment-298130034).

A new, different set of image resampling functions is apparently in the pipeline. In the meantime, you can find some examples on the web on how to do that yourself using e.g. [transposed convolutions](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/11/22/upsampling-and-image-segmentation-with-tensorflow-and-tf-slim/). It is unfortunately much less efficient that per-channel upsampling, but correct is better than fast.

**EDIT**

They finally fixed this bug in [TF 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0):

> - `image.resize` now considers proper pixel centers (...).

This fix currently does not pass gradient through, which is... a bug that will hopefully also get fixed.

Comment: Seems it produce same results as opencv resize also with `tensorflow=1.14.0` with `tensorflow.compat.v2` and `antialias=False` https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6720#issuecomment-520638909

Answer (score 1):

Keras supports `'nearest'` and `'bilinear'` interpolation now with tensorflow backend. Check the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#upsampling2d). But the default size value is indeed (2,2) or int value, so in that case your upsampling will be at least double.

This code needs `Keras 2.2.3` or above. If you are using `tf.keras`, unfortunately, you cannot install keras separately, it is bundled as part of tensorflow installation. Hence either find the `tf` version or install the  nightly build.

`pip3 install --upgrade tf-nightly`